# How to rewrite this url using htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this url, http://website.com/?slug=product_info.php&products_id=28

and wanted to rewrite it to:
http://website.com/page/product_info/product_id/28

How to do this using the htaccess or the function "wp_rewrite" of wordpress?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the .htaccess file you can try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/? /?slug=$1&$2=$3 [QSA,L]
```

This will make it so when you type http://website.com/page/product_info/product_id/28 into your browser's address bar, it gets rewritten internally on the server into `/?slug=product_info.php&products_id=28`.

If you meant the *other way* around, the rewrite will look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^slug=([^&]+)&([^=]+)=([^&]+)
RewriteRule . /page/%1/%2/%3 [L]
```

So this will make it so when you type http://website.com/?slug=product_info.php&products_id=28 into your browser's address bar, it gets rewritten internally on the server into `/page/product_info/product_id/28`.